# Transfer data in WPF using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm stuck in this for too long and I just need someone to show me the direction...

The thing is that Im trying to develop using MVVM pattern and I can't seem to know how can I transfer some data from a method and bind it to my XAML. Also I have problems with setting up an interface ( INotifyPropertyChanged ) in all this structure. Could any of you show where does it have to be implemented?

I will try to explain on my code...

I have a DataModel that for example will be an API that will fetch some data from the web:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string apiResult = "null";

    private void GetDataFromApi()
    {
        // Some web service
        apiResult = "SOME RESULT FROM WEB API";
    }
}
```

Now I have a ViewModel for the logic:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private DataModel dm = new DataModel();

    public string ApiResult
    {
        get { return dm.apiResult; }
        set { dm.apiResult = value; }
    }

    public void GetApi()
    {
        dm.GetDataFromApi();
    }
}
```

And finaly the View:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFexample" x:Class="WPFexample.MainWindow"
    DataContext="{Binding ''}"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="110,126,0,0" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="{Binding ApiResult}"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.296,-1.239">
        <TextBlock.DataContext>
            <local:ViewModel/>
        </TextBlock.DataContext>
    </TextBlock>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Actually I don't know how I can implement this as my "apiResult" is always the initial value "null", and I want it to get the result from the METHOD *GetDataFromApi*

How can I get all this working in the MVVM, and with some interface implemented.

I have looked at various tutorials but cant seem to grasp it as they all have something lacking from the beginning or I don't quite understand the logic...

Have also pushed this to GIT: https://github.com/lklancir/WPFexample/tree/master/WPFexample/WPFexample

Hope you can just point me in the right direction...

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling `DataModel.GetDataFromApi()` anywhere.

Comment: I tried calling it in the ViewModel but nothing happens when I go trough debugger

Comment: Then please post that code. As it stands, your question will be closed. It is very obvious that `ApiResult` is going to be null since you're not populating it anywhere.

Comment: I have now, but I don't think this is good... I know I could call this method in the constructor of the form in _MainWindow.xaml.cs_ after InitializeCompoenent but is that in the MVVM structure then?

Comment: Just a suggestion: MVVM is an advanced pattern and WPF is an advanced framework, certainly these are not suitable for beginners. I suggest you get familiar with C# and OOP concepts in general by writing some console applications before trying to get into complex WPF/MVVM UIs, since you seem to be lacking some fundamental understanding of how object instances and methods work together. You're never calling the `public void GetApi()` method anywhere. Your data is still never retrieved.

Comment: I know, I've been programming for some time now... I just cant remember how can I call methods in this kind of pattern as I want to keep it seperated. I know how I would do this in some classical WindowsForm or console application but I can't get the grip in this arhitecture as at one point I have to be a beginner in this also :)

Comment: Well ask yourself when *should* the results be obtained. By user interaction (e.g. clicking a refresh button), or periodically on a timer. Or just once and only once at 'load' time? Each of those will have a different implementation, and that last one could have its own race-condition with regards to the construction of the window, depending on when you make the call and whether you raise property changed notifications.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, if GetDataFromApi is actually called. Add this code to DataModel.cs and the gui shows "SOME RESULT FROM WEB API"

```
 public DataModel()
 {
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => this.GetDataFromApi() );
 }
```

But this is a timing issue. If you add a sleep to the task it will no longer work, because nothing propagates changes of the properties. You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged or use DependencyProperties.

Comment: This is very advanced :D . Ah so I have to call a constructor here? And yes, I don't really know how to implement the interface in this

Comment: The constructor is called automatically. But somewhere in your code, you have to call GetDataFromApi. I thought that using a task would simulate an asynchronous read from some kind of api. But I think the key is that WPF is not informed about changes. It just reads the value on time. If you want to trigger updated, you have to inform WPF about the changes. This is normally done with INotifyPropertyChanged.